# Is there a thread on this site where someone can practice mardown

Tags: support, markdown

I've been trying to use markdown in comments and they never come out right.

When starting a thread, the system show what the markdown will eventually produce before you submit it. That's great. Responding by adding a comment has no such preview facility and every time I hit the enter key to get to a new line (force of habit) it uploads an unfinished comment. That's rude.

I'd like to have a practice thread where anyone can just add comments. Is that asking too much?

Answer (score 6):

The [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) sounds like what you’re looking for.

Note that:

- You can’t use newlines or paragraphs in comments anyways
- Comments use a sparser Markdown syntax:

  - `` ` `` delimits code; if you need to use exactly one backslash, surround it with multiple backticks
  - Bold and italic work as usual
  - Links have to use the `[Link](http://example.com "Optional title")` syntax in comments
  - There are some link shortcuts. A few examples are:

    - `[tag:whatever]` and `[meta-tag:whatever]`
    - `[help]`
    - `[so]`, `[meta]`, `[main]`, `[somesiteshortname.se]`

Comment: I was *about* to click "post your answer" and you beat me to it :P +1